# Naming conventions and file placement using Bower and Gulp

Tags: node.js, build, npm, gulp, bower

I started working with Bower and Gulp just recently. I have a `bower.json` listing my dependencies, a `gulpfile.js` with tasks for fonts, css, js, etc. and a `package.json` listing gulp dependencies, among other things.

I have only those files under version control and as a test checked out the repository elsewhere and managed to install the gulp and bower dependencies, and to build everything with gulp. I then have the directories `bower_components`, `node_modules` and `build`, which is created by gulp.

What is now the normal place to put my own code? Should I simply create another directory, `src` or `app` or so in the root of the project, and let gulp minify it etc. and put it in the `build` directory?

Are there any naming conventions that I should be aware of?

So, my current directory structure is:

- Root

  - bower_components

    - bootstrap, bootswatch, jquery, ...
  - node_modules

    - gulp, gulp-*, ...
  - build

    - assets

      - css, fonts, img, js, ...
  - bower.json
  - gulpfile.json
  - package.json

Comment: None... feel free to go with any :) `src` and `app` are common ones, but it varies depending on the community you're in (Google uses `app` for the application and `dist` for the built files)

Comment: seems like your on the right track... creating your working directory (or src) folder should be cool - just make sure to update your gulpfile.js to be watching those folders inside src. If you post your current folder structure i can probably be of more help.

Comment: @r00k I included my current directory structure. Then I'll just add another directory `src` and edit the gulpfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if you were to add a (src) directory to the root, where your structure looks like

|src

|-src/  img

|-src/ js

|-src/  less-css

your "watch" task may look something like this

```
    gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Watch .less files
  gulp.watch('./src/less/**/*.less', ['styles']);

  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('./src/img/*', ['images']);

  // Create LiveReload server
  // livereload.listen();  // only if you use livereload

  // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['assets/**']).on('change', livereload.changed);

});
```

When running `gulp watch` from that project's directory, any changes to files listed in the paths above will be noticed, and changes will be built from the src into your 'build' folder (depending how you setup the rest of your gulp file)

But as ddprrt mentioned, its really community preference how you name your source directory.